# C preprocessor default additions

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

Taking the following stub program with no imports:

```
int main(void) {
    return 0;
}
```

Running the `cpp` on it gives me:

```
$ cpp main.c

# 1 "main.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 31 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 32 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "main.c"


int main(void) {
    return 0;
}
```

I understand it adding in `# 1 "main.c"` meaning `#line 1 "main.c"` or "Here is line 1 of the given `main.c` program. I am keen to learn what all the rest of the `cpp` lines do. For example, this segment:

```
# 1 "main.c"           <-- why necessary if we have this after the last line and re-defined?
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 31 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 32 "<command-line>" 2
```

Comment: It starts reading at `main.c` line 1.  Then it injects all the built-in macros if any.  Then it goes back to `main.c` to read the actual input file.  The first `# 1 "main.c"` one really isn't necessary, it's probably just an artifact of the implementation.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Line-Control.html: "The C preprocessor informs the C compiler of the location in your source code where each token came from."  And these directives are how it does that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The CPP command and its output

When you use the `cpp` command, the C Preprocessor will produce a **textual** ouput, differently from when it is used from within the compiler, when it will only pass some resulting binary tokens to the compiler itself.

So, the textual output that you are reading is much like a "debugging" or "logging", (or "*storytelling*" if you prefer) session of what the preprocessor is doing and how. It will basically talk you through on how it is expanding the macros found.

So, as you already found out, the preprocessor is outputting the line number information and the source file name, in a line of the following format:

`# linenum filename {flags}`

called `linemarker`, and literally meaning:

> This line was found in the file named `filename` at line `linenum`

If any flags are specified, they can range from 1 to 4 and mean the following:

- 1 -> Starting a new file.
- 2 -> After including another file, coming back to a previous file.
- 3 -> The contents of this text are taken from a system header, so some warnings are suppressed.
- 4 -> Wraps the content of the text into an `extern "C"` block

### Let's analyse these lines one by one:

- `# 1 "main.c"`

The following line was at `line 1` of `main.c`, with no other flags. So, it's like saying "I am starting to read line 1 of main.c"

- `# 1 "<built-in>"`

I am now going to read a **built-in** C pre-procssor directive. Note how these are shown a `<System Header>`, but this if fictious. This line, therefore, sets a standard predefined macro, like _*LINUX*_ or *__cplusplus*.

Read more about those [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html#Standard-Predefined-Macros)

**Bonus tip:** run `cpp -dM main.c` to see all your predefined macros.

- `# 1 "<command-line>"`

I am now going to read a command-line option, so one of those which were set by the `-D` flag, like `-DTEST=0`, or even command-line **undefinitions**, like `-UTEST`. These are again presented from the preprocessor as a fictious system header file.

Read more about Preprocessor options [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html)

- `# 31 "<command-line>"`

At line 31, I am reading another macro coming from the command-line. (Note these are set in the order they are found)

- `# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4`

I will read the pre-defined macros file, located at `/usr/include/stdc-predef.h` assuring that this header will be included like a system file header and that the symbols it contains are treated as **C** symbols.

- `# 32 "<command-line>" 2`

I am resuming the reading of the command-line "pseudo-header", and I will finish reading it.

- `# 1 "main.c"`

I will now resume reading `main.c`

Comment: thanks for this great answer. Wow, a lot of macros defined, I have about 400 on my machine when I run `-dM`.

Comment: No problem! You can read about different -dletter flags [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) if you are interested and want to tailor the displayed macros output